# List Results in a Table - While Loop and List Results in TD Also

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to find the answer for this but having no joy.  I have a while loop that gives me numerous rows outputted in a table.  It's here:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.winner AS horseWinner, a.twitter_pubstatus,
a.market, a.racetime, a.racecourse, a.date_dd, a.date_mm, b.username, b.course, 
b.horse,b.type, b.racetime, b.dd, b.mm FROM results a 
INNER JOIN bets b ON a.winner = b.horse WHERE a.twitter_pubstatus = 0 
AND a.market = '$win' AND b.type = '$userwin' 
AND a.date_dd = b.dd AND a.date_mm = b.mm GROUP BY a.winner");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['horseWinner'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is all well and good but the issue lies that there is more than one username that is per horseWinner.  I have tried to do another while loop within a while loop.  So I would like it to list the usernames in the second column seperated by comma.

Many thanks

Comment: You could either edit your query and add a `GROUP_CONCAT` on the `username`, or create a php array first with your returned data and then build your table from the php array.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on your `username` so that it returns a comma separated list -

```
SELECT a.winner AS horseWinner, a.twitter_pubstatus,
a.market, a.racetime, a.racecourse, a.date_dd, a.date_mm, 

GROUP_CONCAT(b.username) as username, 

b.course, b.horse,b.type, b.racetime, b.dd, b.mm FROM results a 
INNER JOIN bets b ON a.winner = b.horse WHERE a.twitter_pubstatus = 0 
AND a.market = '$win' AND b.type = '$userwin' 
AND a.date_dd = b.dd AND a.date_mm = b.mm GROUP BY a.winner
```

Comment: Just did this from your comment, worked a treat.  Should've know this but thank you very much for the heads up.  Will mark as correct as soon as it lets me!